# How to replace double quotes to a space in VBScript?

Tags: regex, replace, vbscript

I need open the `CSV file`, replace the double quotes with space and save the new file with `txt extension`.

I have tried this `VBScript` code but the first file `Output_D1.txt` is empty, the `Output_D2.txt` file contains rows of the `Output_D1.csv`, the `Output_D3.txt` file contains rows of the `Output_D2.csv`... etc.

How to do resolve this ?

```
   nArr = Array("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6")   

   Set reP = new RegExp  
   reP.Pattern = "\"""     

   For I = 0 To UBound(nArr) 
      InFilename = "Output_" & nArr(I) & ".csv"
      Set FILE1 = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
      Set infile = FILE1.OpenTextFile(InFileName, 1, False)   
      strg = reP.Replace(strg, " ")
      InFilenameNew = "Output_" & nArr(I) & ".txt"
      Set Outfile = File1.CreateTextFile(inFileNameNew, 1, False)
      Outfile.Write(strg) 
      strg = infile.ReadAll
      infile.Close  
   Next
```

Comment: Try = `WSH.Echo (Replace(strg,""""," "))`

Comment: Just use normal `Replace()` instead of `RegExp.Replace()` - [How to use Replace function in VBScript](//stackoverflow.com/q/42775373).

Comment: @scientist_7 I have the same problem, thanks ---

Comment: @LankymartI have the same problem, thanks ---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- You need to set the RegExp global option to replace all occurences of quotes
- You need the full path to the CSV files (see rootFolder for a hard-coded example)
- ReadAll is used in the wrong place (it needed to be before the RegExp replace!)

  ```
  Option Explicit 

  dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  dim rootFolder : rootFolder = "C:\Temp\"
  dim nArr : nArr = Array("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6")   
  dim i, inFilename, inFilenameNew, infile, outfile, filecontent
  Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2

  dim reP : Set reP = new RegExp 
  reP.Global = true
  reP.Pattern = "\"""     

  For i = 0 To UBound(nArr) 
      inFilename = rootFolder & "Output_" & nArr(i) & ".csv"
      inFilenameNew = rootFolder & "Output_" & nArr(i) & ".txt"   

      if (fso.FileExists(inFilename)) Then
          Set infile = fso.OpenTextFile(InFileName, ForReading) 
          filecontent = infile.ReadAll
          filecontent = reP.Replace(filecontent, " ")
          infile.Close
          Set infile = Nothing

          Set outfile = fso.CreateTextFile(inFileNameNew, True)
          outfile.Write(filecontent)
          outfile.Close  
          Set outfile = Nothing
      End If          
  Next 

  Set reP = Nothing
  Set fso = Nothing
  ```